# Error setting a function to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
function getImage(query){
    var serach_title = query.replace(/\ /g, '+');
    var imgUrl = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q="+serach_title;
    $.ajax({
        url: imgUrl,
        cache: false,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            var image = data.responseData.results[0].unescapedUrl;
            console.log(image);
            return image;
        }
    });
}
```

and when I set this function to a veraible like so:

```
var image = getImage(title);
```

the `var image` coming back with `undefined`. but `console.log(image);` is logging the url correctly.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: declare image in the outer scope of the function, rather than inside the ajax success. have you tried this?

Comment: are you not trying to do var image = new getImage(); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function getImage is not valid. It returns result immediately, but ajax request is async. So, you should use callback function, which will be called when request is executed.

```
function getImage(query, callback) {
    var serach_title = query.replace(/\ /g, '+');
    var imgUrl = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q="+serach_title;
    $.ajax(
        url: imgUrl,
        cache: false, 
        dataType:'jsonp', 
        success: function(data) {
            var img = data.responseData.results[0].unescapedUrl;
            if (callback) {
                callback(img);
            }
    });
}

// here you should show progress... 
var image; 
getImage(query, function(img) {
    image= img;
});
```

Another way is to use jQuery deferred object to get result from ajax request:

```
function getImage(query) {
   var serach_title = query.replace(/\ /g, '+');
   var imgUrl = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q="+serach_title;
   return $.get(imgUrl, null, 'jsonp');
}

// here you should show progress... 
var image;
getImage(query).done(function(data) {
   image = data.responseData.results[0].unescapedUrl;
});
```

Comment: no, you should use [jQuery deffered objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object)

Comment: take a look at my answer, same idea using callback - too slow to post it. i got an example usage also

Comment: If you will use the image variable defined in one context, than of course it will be work. The second ajax call rewrite the image value.

Answer (score 0):

ajax call here is async, so you can solve this using js callback like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// function
function getImage(query, callback){
    var serach_title = query.replace(/\ /g, '+');
    var imgUrl = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q="+serach_title;
    $.ajax({
        url: imgUrl,
        cache: false,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            callback({
                image: data.responseData.results[0].unescapedUrl
            });
        }
    });
}

// usage
getImage('apple', function(e)
{
    // after request is made to google and you have a result
    console.log(e.image);
})

</script>
```

my console output:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Put you return into the ajax function:

```
function getImage(query){
    var serach_title = query.replace(/\ /g, '+');
    var imgUrl = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q="+serach_title;
    $.ajax({
        url: imgUrl,
        cache: false, 
        dataType:'jsonp', 
        success: function(data) {
            return data.responseData.results[0].unescapedUrl;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are getting image asynchronously. This can simply be done by making the ajax call as synchronous.

```
$.ajax({
    url: imgUrl,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType:'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        var image = data.responseData.results[0].unescapedUrl;
        console.log(image);
        return image;
    }
});
```